# Tor hidden service - programmatically add a service without using the torrc file

Tags: tor

I know how to setup a hidden service in the torrc file and it works, I am very new to this. if anyone could point me in the right direction I don't mind the hard work to learn something.

Answer (score 0):

To programmatically create a hidden service, send the `ADD_ONION` command to the Tor controller. This requires that `ControlPort` is set in the `torrc` file and that you have set up some form of authentication.

For details, see [`ADD_ONION`](https://gitweb.torproject.org/torspec.git/tree/control-spec.txt?id=660a75f34d82e7b9ea2a632dd1f0e06ad17b00d5#n1659) from Section 3 (Commands) of the Tor control-spec document.

The Python [`stem`](https://stem.torproject.org) library supports this and has examples: https://stem.torproject.org/tutorials/over_the_river.html#running-a-hidden-service

In PHP the [`torutils`](https://github.com/dapphp/TorUtils) library has an example here: https://github.com/dapphp/TorUtils/blob/master/examples/tc_CreateHiddenService.php